# Select multiple rows in MySQL table based on a comma delimited string

Tags: mysql, ignition

I have an application with a page that lists inventory. At the top of the page is a search text-box where users can enter values, such as an id, a name, location etc. I want users to be able to enter multiple values into the search text box and for MySQL to return a row for every value that is found.

I am looking for a pure MySQL solution, not PHP or Python...

Ex. Search string: "161, Bob, Production, 123, 125" where all the values correspond to different columns (i.e. the integers are the ID, Bob is a possible first name and Production is a location). MySQL would then search for each comma separated value and if found, return a row. Preferably this would be done in one query, not sequentially, where the first is found, displayed, then the second one, etc..

Comment: You need some form of server language to ensure that SQL injection doesn't happen. A jquery based search could make the results dynamic as the user types the string.

Answer (score 1):

You need the SQL [`IN` operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

Something like this will do what you are looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE table_name.id IN (161, 'Bob', 'Production', 123, 125)
OR table_name.first_name IN (161, 'Bob', 'Production', 123, 125)
OR table_name.location IN (161, 'Bob', 'Production', 123, 125)
```